# MS Project Server 2013 for development purposes

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, sharepoint, ms-project-server-2013

I have a j2ee application and I need to send GET REST queries in MS Project Server REST api to synchronize projects and tasks of my application.

Is there a quick way to test this case like a Microsoft online test environment with sample data? Do I need to set up all these Microsoft products (prerequisites like SharePoint and Microsoft Server OS) to test that my restful client gets the appropriate xml response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to handle the whole Sharepoint/Projectserver thing yourself your best bet could be would be: getting a Project Server Online subscription or Demo:

https://products.office.com/en-us/project/project-online-with-project-pro-for-office-365

It's a full Project Server (with everything below it) online. You can not run server side code but you have access to the REST Services.

Bye
Klaus